# Django makemigrations - No installed app with label '<appname>'

Tags: python, django

Beginner to Django Web Frameworks here...when I try to run python manage.py makemigration courses, it throws this error:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations courses
←[31;1mNo installed app with label 'courses'.
```

Here is what I have in settings.py for INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'courses.apps',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

This is in my apps.py file:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class CoursesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Courses'
```

Here is what python manage.py showmigrations gives:

```
$ python manage.py showmigrations
←[1madmin
←[0m [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
 [X] 0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices
←[1mauth
←[0m [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
 [X] 0010_alter_group_name_max_length
 [X] 0011_update_proxy_permissions
 [X] 0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length
←[1mcontenttypes
←[0m [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
←[1msessions
←[0m [X] 0001_initial
```

Also, why do I have these '←[31;1m' and '←[0m' symbols in the output on my terminal? I am using VSCode

Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me. Use the same case in the name.

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class CoursesConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'courses'  # Instead of 'Courses'
```

Then in your settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'courses',  # or courses.apps.CoursesConfig
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `installed_app` array like this below

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'courses.apps.CoursesConfig',
    .....
]
```

If you keep it like this, still it will work

```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'courses',
        .....
    ]
```

Comment: Hi anamul, I have changed it to 'courses.apps.CoursesConfig' in INSTALLED_APPS however when I run python manage.py makemigrations courses, I get this error:
```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'Courses'. Check that 'courses.apps.CoursesConfig.name' is correct.
```